# singular matrix or not: conflict between determinant and rank

Tags: r, matrix

I made a correlation matrix from exponentially smoothed returns, using Appendix C in https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/65527/2/01_Pozzi_Exponential_smoothing_weighted_2012.pdf as a guide.

It's a 101 by 101 matrix, but I don't know if it is singular or not, due to the following conflicting results:

- `pracma::Rank` says its rank is 101;
- `matrixcalc::is.singular.matrix` returns TRUE;
- `base::determinant.matrix` gives a very close-to-zero value.

```
pracma::Rank(try.wgtd.cor)
#[1] 101
matrixcalc::is.singular.matrix(try.wgtd.cor)
#[1] TRUE
base::determinant.matrix(try.wgtd.cor, logarithm = FALSE)
#$modulus
#[1] 2.368591e-55
#attr(,"logarithm")
#[1] FALSE
#
#$sign
#[1] 1
#
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "det"
```

Does anyone know why/how this could be?

Comment: Lack of precision. With the determinant that close to 0 you should consider it singular.

Comment: Okay, I kind of figured. Thank you.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi your answer below was very helpful. Thank you. I'm realizing I need to walk before I run, when it comes to quantitative stuff. I'm revisiting a basic linear algebra text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No no no, don't rely on determinant. A small determinant does not necessarily means singularity. For example, the following diagonal matrix is not singular at all, but has a very small determinant.

```
## all diagonal elements are 0.1; dimension 101 x 101
D <- diag(0.1, nrow = 101, ncol = 101)

## the obvious way to compute det(D)
prod(diag(D))
#[1] 1e-101

## use base::determinant.matrix
determinant.matrix(D, logarithm = FALSE)$modulus
#[1] 1e-101
```

The determinant equals the product of eigenvalues. So in general, if all eigenvalues of a matrix are smaller than 1, then the determinant will be very small for sure!

`matrixcalc::is.singular.matrix` is based on determinant, so do not trust it. In addition, its result is too subjective because you can tweak `tol`:

[image: doc]

By contrast, `pracma::Rank` uses both QR and SVD factorizations to determine rank. The result is extremely reliable. Here is the source code of `Rank` (with my comments):

```
function (M) 
{
    if (length(M) == 0) 
        return(0)
    if (!is.numeric(M)) 
        stop("Argument 'M' must be a numeric matrix.")
    if (is.vector(M)) 
        M <- matrix(c(M), nrow = length(M), ncol = 1)
    ## detect rank by QR factorization
    r1 <- qr(M)$rank
    ## detect rank by SVD factorization
    sigma <- svd(M)$d
    tol <- max(dim(M)) * max(sigma) * .Machine$double.eps
    r2 <- sum(sigma > tol)
    ## check consistency
    if (r1 != r2) 
        warning("Rank calculation may be problematic.")
    return(r2)
}
```

In conclusion, your 101 x 101 matrix `try.wgtd.cor` actually has full rank!